# Setting a service for IMemoryCache

Tags: asp.net

Working with ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)

I have extended my own logic as follows:

```
public interface IMemoryCache : Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache
```

How to configure `ConfigureServices` for my implementation? In other words, how can I configure a service (at `Startup.cs` file) for interface that inherits an interface?

Answer (score 0):

In `Startup.cs` add:

```
services.AddCaching();
```

([Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFiJY.png))

You then need to inject caching into your controller or class:

[DI MemoryCache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba9xR.png)